# adding answer count to view when moderating answers

Tags: feature-request

I've recently had a comment left on an answer to my own question that I left because it looked like I wrote a short answer saying thanks, when infact, I was just answering it, and saying thanks to the community. My answer was the only answer (no comments) at the time, so I couldn't have been saying thanks to any other one else.

I understand the question isn't included in the view the moderators see, but maybe the answer count / comment count could be included to prevent such future problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, they [do see the question when reviewing the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5482561). It even states the number of other answers that exist on the question. Some people just don't look at it, or don't read past the word "thanks" when they see it. Note that any user with at least 2,000 reputation can access that queue, and the user who left that comment is not a moderator.